# What does red interrupted line mean in autolayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

What does red interrupted line mean in autolayout see below on picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the official guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html

Misplaced or ambiguous constraints are shown in orange, conflicting constraints are red.